# Passing setter to the child component in react trivia app

Tags: reactjs, state, setter

I am currently building trivia app in React. When I click on correct answer it turns green and when click on wrong it turn red and correct answer turns green. As expected. I want to update the score in Header component. When I pass the setter from App.js to Question component as props and use it in handleAnswer function, then when click on correct answer it update the score but it does not turn green, answers are reshuffling and when I click on it many times it just add up the score.
Also the countdown useEffect is messing everything up. Any help will be much appreciated.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Question from './components/Question'
import axios from 'axios';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

function App() {

  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([])
  const [nextButtonClicked, setNextButtonClicked] = React.useState({
    isClicked: false,
    value: 0,
  })
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(30)
  const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0)
  
  // useEffect to get new set of 10 questions
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
    .then((res) => {
      const response = res.data;
      setQuestions(response.results);
      
    })},[])

  //useEffect to count down 30s time
  /*
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);
  */
  
  // helper function for randomly show answers
  function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }
 
 
  const questionElements = questions.map(element => {
    
    let answers = [
                   [element.correct_answer, true], 
                   [element.incorrect_answers[0], false],
                   [element.incorrect_answers[1], false],
                   [element.incorrect_answers[2], false]
                  ]

    let shuffledAnswers = shuffle(answers);
    console.log(shuffledAnswers);
    console.log("answer")

    
  

    return (
              
              <Question 
                  key={nanoid()}
                  question={JSON.stringify(element.question)} 
                  answers={shuffledAnswers}
                  setScore={setScore}
                  
            />
             
      )
    })
  
  
  
  function nextQuestion() {
      
      setNextButtonClicked(prevState => ({
      isClicked: true,
      value: prevState.value + 1
    })
   ) 
  }
  
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Header counter={counter} score={score} nextButtonClicked={nextButtonClicked}/>
      {questionElements}
      {
        nextButtonClicked.isClicked ? questionElements[nextButtonClicked.value] : questionElements[0]
      }
      <button onClick={nextQuestion} className='next-question-button'>Next Question</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Question.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function Question(props) {
    
    const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = React.useState(false)

    function handleAnswer(e) {
        if (e.target.ariaLabel === "true") {
            setCorrectAnswer(false)
            e.target.classList.add("green-button")
            
            props.setScore(prevState => prevState + 1)
        } else {
            e.target.classList.add("red-button")
            setCorrectAnswer(true)
        }
    }
    
    
    function decode(uri) {
        
        let encoded = encodeURI(uri)
        let decoded = decodeURI(encoded)
        return decoded.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")
    }
    
    return ( 
        
        <div className="question-container">
             
             <h2 className="question">{decode(props.question)}</h2>
                <div className="answers-container">
                    {props.answers[0][0] !== undefined && <button  
                                                              onClick={e=>handleAnswer(e)} 
                                                              className={props.answers[0][1] === true && correctAnswer === true ? "answer-button green-button" : "answer-button"} 
                                                              aria-label={props.answers[0][1]}>{props.answers[0]}
                                                          </button>}
                    {props.answers[1][0] !== undefined && <button  
                                                              onClick={e=>handleAnswer(e)} 
                                                              className={props.answers[1][1] === true && correctAnswer === true ? "answer-button green-button" : "answer-button"} 
                                                              aria-label={props.answers[1][1]}>{props.answers[1]}
                                                          </button>}
                    {props.answers[2][0] !== undefined && <button  
                                                              onClick={e=>handleAnswer(e)} 
                                                              className={props.answers[2][1] === true && correctAnswer === true ? "answer-button green-button" : "answer-button"} 
                                                              aria-label={props.answers[2][1]}>{props.answers[2]}
                                                          </button>}
                    {props.answers[3][0] !== undefined && <button  
                                                              onClick={e=>handleAnswer(e)} 
                                                              className={props.answers[3][1] === true & correctAnswer === true ? "answer-button green-button" : "answer-button"} 
                                                              aria-label={props.answers[3][1]}>{props.answers[3]}
                                                          </button>}
                </div>  
   
        </div>
       
    )
}

export default Question;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Header(props) {
    
    return (
        
        <div className="header">
            <h1 className="trivia">Trivia</h1>
            <h2 className="header-time">{props.counter}</h2>
            <div className='score'>
    <h3 className="header-text header-score">score: {props.score} | #{props.nextButtonClicked.value}</h3>
              <h3 className="header-text">easy</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

style.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F5F7FB;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}


.header {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 17vh;
  background-color: rgb(122, 132, 186);
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: large;
}


.question-container {
  background-color: rgb(245, 188, 81);
  width: 80vw;
  height: 65vh;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.question {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-self: center;
}
.trivia {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

.score {
  display: flex;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 10px;;
}
.header-text {
  margin: 10px;
  
}
.header-time {
  color: antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: #4D5B9E;
}
.answer-button {
  background-color: azure;
  color:gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 0.794239px solid #4D5B9E;
  border-radius: 7.94239px;
}

.next-question-button {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: rgb(122, 132, 186);
  
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .answers-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.green-button {
  background-color: rgb(37, 206, 37);
  color: black;
}
.red-button {
  background-color: rgb(240, 80, 80);
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: You should share the css file so people can reproduce the problem

Comment: Hi Hasan, sorry, all done.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the user clicks the correct answer button, the parent `score` gets updated which leads to re-render and creation of a new shuffled list of buttons. the `correctAnswer` flag gets overwritten on every render.

The correct answer button is never colored green because a new button takes its place immediately.

Solution: move the answer button to its own component. this simplifies the task of handling correct/wrong answer.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-river-rtoywq?file=/src/App.js)

Also, the `decoder` function was not working since you are encoding and decoding the input at the same time, you either decode or encode.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Question from "./components/Question";
import Header from "./components/Header";

import axios from "axios";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([]);
  const [nextButtonClicked, setNextButtonClicked] = React.useState({
    isClicked: false,
    value: 0
  });
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(30);
  const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0);

  // useEffect to get new set of 10 questions
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10").then((res) => {
      const response = res.data;
      setQuestions(response.results);
    });
  }, []);

  //useEffect to count down 30s time
  /*
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);
  */

  // helper function for randomly show answers
  function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  const questionElements = questions.map((element) => {
    let answers = [
      [element.correct_answer, true],
      [element.incorrect_answers[0], false],
      [element.incorrect_answers[1], false],
      [element.incorrect_answers[2], false]
    ];

    let shuffledAnswers = shuffle(answers);

    return (
      <Question
        key={nanoid()}
        question={JSON.stringify(element.question)}
        answers={shuffledAnswers}
        setScore={setScore}
      />
    );
  });

  function nextQuestion() {
    setNextButtonClicked((prevState) => ({
      isClicked: true,
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header
        counter={counter}
        score={score}
        nextButtonClicked={nextButtonClicked}
      />
      {questionElements[nextButtonClicked.value]}

      <button onClick={nextQuestion} className="next-question-button">
        Next Question
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Question.js

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import React from "react";
import AnswerButton from "./Button";

function Question(props) {
  const [showCorrectAnswer, setShowCorrectAnswer] = React.useState(false);

  function decode(uri) {
    let encoded = encodeURI(uri);
    let decoded = decodeURI(encoded);
    return decoded.replaceAll('^"|"$', "");
  }

  return (
    <div className="question-container">
      <h2 className="question">{decode(props.question)}</h2>
      <div className="answers-container">
        {props.answers.map((answer) => (
          <AnswerButton
            key={nanoid()}
            answer={answer}
            showCorrectAnswer={showCorrectAnswer}
            setShowCorrectAnswer={setShowCorrectAnswer}
          />
        ))}
        {/* {props.answers[0][0] !== undefined && (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => handleAnswer(e)}
            className="answer-button"
            aria-label={props.answers[0][1]}
          >
            {props.answers[0][1] ? "true" : "false"}
          </button>
        )}
        {props.answers[1][0] !== undefined && (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => handleAnswer(e)}
            className="answer-button"
            aria-label={props.answers[1][1]}
          >
            {props.answers[1][1] ? "true" : "false"}
          </button>
        )}
        {props.answers[2][0] !== undefined && (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => handleAnswer(e)}
            className="answer-button"
            aria-label={props.answers[2][1]}
          >
            {props.answers[2]}
          </button>
        )}
        {props.answers[3][0] !== undefined && (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => handleAnswer(e)}
            className="answer-button"
            aria-label={props.answers[3][1]}
          >
            {props.answers[3]}
          </button>
        )} */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Question;
```

and finally, Button:

```
const AnswerButton = (props) => {
  if (props.answer[0] === undefined) return;
  const handleAnswer = () => {
    props.setShowCorrectAnswer(true);
  };
  const correctClass = props.answer[1]
    ? "green-button answer-button"
    : "red-button answer-button";
  return (
    <button
      className={props.showCorrectAnswer ? correctClass : "answer-button"}
      onClick={handleAnswer}
      // aria-label={props.answer[1]}
    >
      {props.answer}
    </button>
  );
};

export default AnswerButton;
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan for your hint, but I already tried that and it still gives me unexpected behaviour. It actually show correct answer no matter where I click.The idea of the showCorrectAnswer state is that when I click on the wrong answer I want to highlight correct answer in green, therefore in handleAnswer function I change setShowCorrectAnswer to true, not false. If you copy the code you can see that it all works fine. Once I move that state to parent it all goes tits up. I know I should lift it up in order to update score in the header but atm I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: I see what you mean. I have edited my answer. now the correct and the wrong answers will be colored when user click an answer.